# Flexible Search Query Condition (if else?)

Tags: java, mysql, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub, flexible-search

I have a question, I have to make a query where I have to show in a column the value "yes" or "no" depending on whether or not there is an image on a product.
I have to join the product table this is safe but how can I tell in the query if the "image presence" field is not empty write "no" otherwise "yes".
I hope I have explained. Thank you all.

Comment: https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/complex-query-join-hybris-flexible-search.html  you can find a `case when` example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the CASE statement, here is a quick example from w3schools

```
SELECT CustomerName, City, Country
FROM Customers
ORDER BY
(CASE
    WHEN City IS NULL THEN Country
    ELSE City
END);
```

Something to note, is that depending on the DBMS you're using, the syntax may (or may not) be different

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp